# ImportError loading tensorflow module

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, anaconda

I have problem during import tensorflow.

Here is my recent stack trace:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Vaidik>python
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:52:34) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "F:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: A simple search query "ImportError: DLL load failed tensorflow" leads to [208 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+DLL+load+failed+tensorflow). Did you go through those? Did any of them get you close to solving the problem? What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create a conda environment for the required python version and install tensorflow.

Follow the below steps:

1. conda create -n tf35 -c intel python=3.5 pip numpy

   (tf35 is the environment name)
2. activate tf35
3. conda install -c anaconda tensorflow

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall tf using

```
conda uninstall tensorflow
```

then install it again

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.8.0 --user
```